# Como usar o feature discovery do materialize somente no primeiro acesso a pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Pois bem, eu tenho o feature discovery no meu arquivo js dessa forma:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.tap-target').tapTarget();
     $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
   });
   function closeFeatureDiscovery() {
     $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close');
     $('.tap-target').tapTarget('destroy');
   }
```

Funciona normalmente porém eu gostaria que abrisse somente a primeira vez que a pessoa acessa a página e não a cada pagina que é acessada dentro do site. Fiz umas buscas e alguns recomendam usar o LocalStorage para armazenar o status mas não sei se é mesmo a melhor solução para o caso e também não soube como buscar sobre esse caso específico.

Comment: Não tem como guardar essa informação que já foi aberto uma vez sem utilizar **localStorage** ou um **banco de dados**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual o problema de utilizar localStorage? Você pode sim utilizar, não há nada de anormal ou deselegante fazer isso. Outra forma seria usando um cookie. Exemplo de localStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (localStorage.getItem('discovered') == null ) { 
       $('.tap-target').tapTarget();
       $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
       localStorage.setItem('discovered', 1);
   };  
})
```

Comment: Legal Isaac! Adotei uma solução bem parecida com essa mas usando ```sessionStorage``` :D